# Displaying images with action in swift?

Tags: iphone, arrays, image, swift, xcode-6.2

I'm a kind new to Xcode/swift, I am trying to build a game where 5 pics need to selected randomly, my code looks something like that :

```
var options = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","4.png"]

@IBAction func option1(sender: AnyObject) {

    var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
    **iphoneChoise.image(options[randomNumber])**   /*This line is not correct*/     

}
```

Please help!

Comment: Are saving the images in Images.xcassets?

Comment: Where you can display your image? I'm asking for what of control iphoneChoise is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an `@IBOutlet` for your image view.

Then, assuming your images are saved in Images.xcassets:

```
@IBAction func option1(sender:AnyObject){
    var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
    yourImageViewIBOutlet.image = UIImage(named: options[randomNumber])
}
```

Comment: Thanks boidkan, That worked for me and the reason that my code didn't work too, Is the first time I put UIImage as subclass for the outlet of the image view in stead on UIImageView .. Thanks !

Comment: Ooh, Didn't I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like :

```
yourImageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
```

In you case, it should like like this :

```
var options = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","4.png"]

@IBAction func option1(sender: AnyObject) {
    var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
    iphoneChoise.image = UIImage(named: options[randomNumber])
}
```

Make sure the images are within the project (inside the `Images.xcassets` for example).

*If it didn't helped, please provide more information : "what" is _iphoneChoise_ and what error are you facing.*

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code for your random image by using the following code:

```
var randomImageGeneratorNumber = acr4random_uniform(5) + 1
YourImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(randomImageGeneratorNumber).png")
```

This is called "String Interpolation"

Hope this will help you by making your code a bit shorter.